# s3cmd count lines with zcat and grep

Tags: shell, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I need to count the number of entries in a zipped (.gz) file from a S3 bucket containing certain characters. How could I do it?

Specifically, my S3 bucket is `s3://mys3.com/`. Under that, there are thousands of buckets like the following:

```
s3://mys3.com/bucket1/
s3://mys3.com/bucket2/
s3://mys3.com/bucket3/
           ...
s3://mys3.com/bucket2000/
```

In each of the bucket, there are about hundreds of zipped(.gz) JSON objects like the following:

```
s3://mys3.com/bucket1/file1.gz
s3://mys3.com/bucket1/file2.gz
s3://mys3.com/bucket1/file3.gz
           ...
s3://mys3.com/bucket1/file100.gz
```

Each of the zipped file contains about 20,000 JSON objects (Each JSON object is a line). In each of the JSON object, there are certain fields containing the word "request". I want to count how many JSON objects are there in bucket1 containing the word "request". I tried this but it did not work:

```
zcat s3cmd --recursive ls s3://mys3.com/bucket1/ | grep "request" | wc -l
```

I do not have a lot of shell experiences, so could anyone help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone is interested:

```
s3cmd ls --recursive s3://mys3.com/bucket1/ | awk '{print $4}' | grep '.gz' | xargs -I@ s3cmd get @ - | zgrep 'request' | wc -l
```